# Удалить дубликаты в массиве String[] в Java

Tags: массивы, java

Приветствую! тема может и заезжанная, но решения я так и не нашел.
Есть массив строк, как удалить (именно удалить дубли, а не просто их найти). Спасибо

Comment: Вариантов два: сдвигать хвост или создавать копию массива, пропуская дубликаты. А дальше? Порядок строк должен сохраняться?

Comment: Вам нужно чтоб элементы в массиве остались только в одном экземпляре?

Comment: Дада, именно

Comment: То, что новый массив это понятно. Порядок роли не играет. Суть в том, чтобы подготовить массив для выборки(реализация фильтра)

Comment: Ну то, что новый массив -- это необязательно. Варианты: заносите строки в множество (например HashSet), затем выбираете. (В множестве одинаковых элементов по одному). Вариант 2: сортируете массив строк, затем копируете строки, которые не совпадают с предыдущей. Но этот вопрос раньше точно был.

Comment: добавляя каждый элемент в HashSet мы автоматическки избавимся от дублей. Ну а потом получившийся HashSet преобразуем в массив.

Comment: @baralgin1003, не забывайте принимать верные ответы!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String[] str = {"aa", "bb", "cc", "aa"};

Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(str));
String[] result = set.toArray(new String[set.size()]);
```

Comment: хотелось бы покороче

Comment: Куда уж короче... Можно две строчки в одну строчку загнать, в принципе:

    String[] result = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(str)).toArray(new String[0]);

Comment: Да. Вот не поставишь смайлик, и начинается...

Comment: Приношу извинения, день тяжелый.

Answer (score 3):

```
void removeDuplicates(String[] array) {
    HashSet<String> hash = new HashSet<String>();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = hash.add(array[i]) ? array[i] : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Простите, я плохо в джавах ориентируюсь, но у меня сомнение. Из `[1, 2, 1, 1, 3]` оно не сделает ли `[1, 2, null, null, 3]` вместо `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: Должно. Убирание null'ей остаётся на Вашу долю

Comment: Если требуется из [1, 2, 1, 1, 3] получить [1, 2, 3], то это не удаление из конкретного массива(объекта) а создание нового без повторений(размер массива не может меняться). Если в вопросе именно это имелось в виду, то моё решение действительно не подходит.

Comment: Действительно, из вопроса не понятно, что именно значит удалить. Может как Вы сделали, может как @Nofate, а может все неповторяющиеся к началу сдвинуть.

Comment: Спасибо! сработал вариант от Nofate, все получилось как надо! 

П.С. кому не жалко, поставьте мне плюсики плиз, а то отвечать на свой вопрос можно только от 50 плюсов.

Comment: @baralgin1003, зачем отвечать на свой ворпрос. Надо отметить ответ за правильный - слева есть галочка в кружкЕ..

Comment: точно) спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.deleteDublicates = function(arr) {
    var uniqs = {}
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        uniqs[arr[i]] ? true : uniqs[arr[i]] = {}
    }
    return Object.keys(uniqs)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String[] sA = {"слова", "которые", "не", "просто", "слова", "а", "массив", "слов"};
String[] sB = new String[sA.length];
HashMap <String, String> shMap  = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (int i = 0; i < sA.length; i++) shMap.put(sA[i], "");
int j=0;
for (int i = 0; i < sA.length; i++) {
    if( shMap.get(sA[i]).equals("")) {
        shMap.put(sA[i], sA[i]);
        sB[j++] = sA[i];
    }
}
System.out.println(sA[i] + " ");
System.out.println(sB[i] + " ");
```